# How to get the current shop in shopify when using NodeJS (Public App)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, shopify, shopify-app

I am new to Shopify App Devlopment, especially the Shopify API.

I create a working app with the Shopify CLI and now want to communicate with the API.

I try to access following endpoint: `https://{my_shop]/admin/api/2021-07/shop.json`

I learned that I need some access token and the shop name to access this endpoint.

I created an access token under my private apps section.

But I dont know how to get the currently logged in store.

For example, when clicking a button in my frontend, I would like to call my endpoint, which in turn calls the Shopify API endpoint and retrieves the information. How do I do this the right way? And how do I get the currently logged in shop?

This is my code so far:

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import createShopifyAuth, { verifyRequest } from "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth";
import Shopify, { ApiVersion } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
import Koa from "koa";
import next from "next";
import Router from "koa-router";
import axios from 'axios';

dotenv.config();
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8081;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({
  dev,
});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  HOST_NAME: process.env.HOST.replace(/https:\/\//, ""),
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October20,
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.MemorySessionStorage(),
});

// Storing the currently active shops in memory will force them to re-login when your server 
restarts. You should
// persist this object in your app.
const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS = {};

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  server.keys = [Shopify.Context.API_SECRET_KEY];
  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      async afterAuth(ctx) {
        // Access token and shop available in ctx.state.shopify
        const { shop, accessToken, scope } = ctx.state.shopify;
        const host = ctx.query.host;
        ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] = scope;

        const response = await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.register({
          shop,
          accessToken,
          path: "/webhooks",
          topic: "APP_UNINSTALLED",
          webhookHandler: async (topic, shop, body) =>
            delete ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop],
        });

        if (!response.success) {
          console.log(
            `Failed to register APP_UNINSTALLED webhook: ${response.result}`
          );
        }

        // Redirect to app with shop parameter upon auth
        ctx.redirect(`/?shop=${shop}&host=${host}`);
      },
    })
  );

  router.get("/test2", verifyRequest(), async(ctx, res) => {
    const {shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
    console.log(shop);
    console.log(accessToken);
  })

  router.get("/test", async (ctx) => {

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': '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'
      }
    }

    await axios.get('${the_store_name_belongs_here}/admin/api/2021-07/shop.json', config).then(res => {
      ctx.body = res.data;
    });
  });

  const handleRequest = async (ctx) => {
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    ctx.respond = false;
    ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
  };

  router.post("/webhooks", async (ctx) => {
    try {
      await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process(ctx.req, ctx.res);
      console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${error}`);
    }
  });

  router.post(
    "/graphql",
    verifyRequest({ returnHeader: true }),
    async (ctx, next) => {
      await Shopify.Utils.graphqlProxy(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    }
  );

  router.get("(/_next/static/.*)", handleRequest); // Static content is clear
  router.get("/_next/webpack-hmr", handleRequest); // Webpack content is clear
  router.get("(.*)", async (ctx) => {
    const shop = ctx.query.shop;

    // This shop hasn't been seen yet, go through OAuth to create a session
    if (ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] === undefined) {
      ctx.redirect(`/auth?shop=${shop}`);
    } else {
      await handleRequest(ctx);
    }
  });


  server.use(router.allowedMethods());
  server.use(router.routes());
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Please have a look at my attempts - endpoint `/test` and endpoint `/test2`.
test2 is not working. ctx.session is null. ctx itself is null. Why?

`test1` is working when I hard code my shops name into the url, then I get the desired data. But how do I put a shop variable inside? That's my struggle.

Comment: Considering you're accessing the `Admin API`, you should be using `shopify-admin-api`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-admin-api
And after the auth, you'd do `const shop = await shops.get();`

Comment: @Ovi could you show an example in an answer? That would be very helpful!

Comment: Do you call the URLs from inside or outside the app?

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu for now, only in the backend

Comment: From what I understand, only the request coming from Shopify has the shop as a query params. What I usually do is that I manually pass the shop as a query params, in the body or the headers.

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu could you try to make an answer with an example? that would be very nice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70084201/5950360 You can check this for a similar issue and it's solution

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is not good practice to use **MemorySessionStorage** in production environment due to its limitations, you can find a good explanation [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/main/docs/usage/customsessions.md)

> *MemorySessionStorage* exists as an option to help you get started
> developing your apps as quickly as possible...

So, implement a **CustomSessionStorage** (refer to the doc above), you will have access to the **session** that stores data such as *shop*, *accessToken*, *scope* among others. As long as authenticated requests are made, providing the JWT in the header, you can get the context properly working.

e.g. (react-koa):

```
//client.js
import { useAppBridge } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import { getSessionToken } from "@shopify/app-bridge-utils";

function Index() {
   const app = useAppBridge();

   async function getProducts() {
       const token = await getSessionToken(app);

       const response = await fetch("/api/products", {
           headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` }
       });

       const result = await response.json();
       console.log(result);
   }

   return (<></>);
}
```

and then...

```
// server.js

router.get("/api/products", verifyRequest({ returnHeader: true }), async (ctx) => {
    // Load the current session to get the `accessToken`.
    // pass a third parameter clarifying the accessMode (isOnline = true by default)
    const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(ctx.req, ctx.res);

    // Create a new client for the specified shop.
    const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest(session.shop, session.accessToken);

    // Use `client.get` to request the specified Shopify REST API endpoint, in this case `products`.
    const products = await client.get({
      path: 'products',
    });

    ctx.body = results.body;
    ctx.res.status = 200;
  });
```

more details [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/main/docs/usage/rest.md).

Using *axios*, you can define it as a hook (working example using TypeScript):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useAppBridge } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import { getSessionToken } from '@shopify/app-bridge-utils';

function useAxios() {
  const app = useAppBridge();
  const instance = axios.create();
  instance.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
    const token = await getSessionToken(app);
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  });
  return [instance];
}

export default useAxios;

// index.js

// ...
const [axios] = useAxios();

// ...
const result = await axios.get('/api/products');
console.log(result.data);
// ...
```

Hope this helps anyone who is still looking for help.

Comment: I confirm this answer is working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem and resolved it by passing the shop as a query parameter.

I call the endpoint with:

```
axios.get('/test', {
  params: {
    shop: 'fo.myshopify.com'
  }
});
```

And get the shop with:

```
router.get("/test", async (ctx) => {
  const shop = ctx.query.shop;
  ...
});
```

Of course, you have to know the shop where you call the endpoint.

Comment: But how do you know the shop? Several different shops will call this endpoint. What is a common way to find out which shop calls the endpoint?

Comment: yes, how do you know the shop? let me know.

Comment: You can store it in the local storage, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference to any `ctx.session` in [koa-shopify-auth documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/koa-shopify-auth). What about this:

```
router.get("/test2", verifyRequest(), async(ctx) => {
  const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.state.shopify;
  console.log(shop, accessToken);
})
```

##### Other solutions

You can store a Cookie after authentication

```
afterAuth(ctx) {
    const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
    ctx.cookies.set("shop", shop, { httpOnly: false, secure: true, sameSite: "none" });
    ctx.redirect("/");
},
```

And then read it in future requests:

```
router.get("/test2", verifyRequest(), async(ctx) => {
  const shop = ctx.cookies.get("shop");
  console.log(shop);
})
```

Comment: From the question: "ctx itself is null". So it's probably not the right way to get the shop.

Comment: yeah, sadly ctx itself is null so no

Comment: I've reproduced your very same example as close as possible and have the context properly working. In `koa` there is no request without context so it is very unlikely the context to be missing. Furthermore the middleware (https://github.com/Shopify/koa-shopify-auth/blob/976e95a1d8fa3628aff4611493c83eb636753c20/src/verify-request/verify-request.ts) has nothing that can mess up the context. Can you provide us a complete example, including `package.json` and anything else required to reproduce the error?

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu from the original question: "ctx.session is null. ctx itself is null". If ctx was null then ctx.session can not be null (being it an invalid accessor). This is why I did not take this sentence as completely true.